# Bukkit / Spigot - PvP rewarding players when falling into void

Tags: java, bukkit

I'm trying to make a rewarding system that reward's you for killing a player.
So i'm done with the basic check, but i want to detect if the victim fell into the void after getting attacked or shot with a bow, the thing is, i couldn't find a solution for that..

Code:

```
    @EventHandler
public void onEntityDamageByEntityEvent(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event) {

    if(!(event.getDamager() instanceof Player) || !(event.getEntity() instanceof Player) ) return;

    String damagerName = event.getDamager().getName();
    String victimName = event.getEntity().getName();

    damageCheck.put(victimName, damagerName);

    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-------------[ X ]-------------");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + damagerName + ChatColor.GRAY + " is the damager");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + victimName + ChatColor.GRAY + " is the victim");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-------------[ X ]-------------");

    Bukkit.getLogger().info(damageCheck.toString());

}

@EventHandler
public void onEntityDeathEvent(EntityDeathEvent event){

    damageCheck.remove(event.getEntity().getName());
    damageCheck.remove(event.getEntity().getKiller().getName());

    event.getEntity().getKiller().sendMessage("You are the killer, and receives rewards!");
    event.getEntity().sendMessage("You died, thats horrible..");

    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-------------[ X ]-------------");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + event.getEntity().getKiller().getName() + ChatColor.GRAY + " is the damager");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + event.getEntity().getName() + ChatColor.GRAY + " is the victim");
    Bukkit.broadcastMessage(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-------------[ X ]-------------");

}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerMovement(PlayerMoveEvent event) {
    Player player = (Player)event.getPlayer();

    // Checking if the players Y
    if(event.getTo().getY() < 25.0) {
        // do stuff here

    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Track past damage, and when it happened, relative to the void damage.

Comment: Would you mind share some code?

Comment: Yes I've added my code

Answer (score 1):

You should surround your `EntityDeathEvent` code with `try & catch` blocks to avoid some errors...

And on the `PlayerMoveEvent`, casting `event.getPlayer()` to `Player` is redundant, since you already specified the variable. Also the Y should be lower than 10, believe me, it's better.

Okay so now you'll first need to check if the hashmap contains that player (who is dying in the void), then get the killer (damager) name from the hashmap, after that you can send a message to that killer and finally kill the player who is in the void

Code :D

```
if (!damageCheck.containsKey(player.getName())) return;

        Player killer = Bukkit.getPlayer(damageCheck.get(player.getName()));
        killer.sendMessage(ChatColor.GREEN + "You've earned " + ChatColor.RED + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "$3" + ChatColor.GREEN + " for killing " + ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + player.getName()); // sends a message to the killer
        player.setHealth(0); // kills the player
```

So we are done with handling the void part. Now you'll need to detect if the victim got shot with a bow:

Change your if statement to `if (!(event.getDamager() instanceof Player || event.getDamager() instanceof Projectile) || !(event.getEntity() instanceof Player)) return;` so it can detect if for example an arrow hit the victim..

Now you'll need to detect the shooter/damager name, this can be done quite easily with an `if` statement.

Code:

```
Player shooterName = event.getDamager() instanceof Projectile ? (Player) ((Projectile) event.getDamager()).getShooter() : null;

String damagerName = event.getDamager() instanceof Player ? event.getDamager().getName() : shooterName.getName();
```

You can also remove `Bukkit.getLogger().info(damageCheck.toString());`, as it's only for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do it like this:

```
private enum Cause {
    ATTACK,
    ARROW,
}

private HashMap<UUID, UUID> lastDamage = new HashMap<UUID, UUID>();
private HashMap<UUID, Cause> lastDamageCause = new HashMap<UUID, Cause>();

@EventHandler
public void onDamage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent e) {
    if (!(e.getEntity() instanceof Player)) {
        return;
    }
    Player damaged = (Player) e.getEntity();
    if (e.getDamager() instanceof Arrow) {
        Arrow a = (Arrow) e.getDamager();
        if (a.getShooter() instanceof Player) {
            Player damager = (Player) a.getShooter();
            lastDamage.put(damaged.getUniqueId(), damager.getUniqueId());
            lastDamageCause.put(damaged.getUniqueId(), Cause.ARROW);
        }
    } else if (e.getDamager() instanceof Player) {
        Player damager = (Player) e.getDamager();
        lastDamage.put(damaged.getUniqueId(), damager.getUniqueId());
        lastDamageCause.put(damaged.getUniqueId(), Cause.ATTACK);
    }
}

@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDeath(PlayerDeathEvent e) {
    Player p = e.getEntity();
    if (e.getDeathMessage().contains("fell out of the world")) {
        if (lastDamage.containsKey(p.getUniqueId())) {
            Player killer = Bukkit.getPlayer(lastDamage.get(p.getUniqueId()));
            Cause cause = lastDamageCause.get(p.getUniqueId());
            switch (cause) {
            case ATTACK:
                //Do whatever you want
                break;
            case ARROW:
                //Do whatever you want
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you just want to check the Y height use `PlayerMoveEvent`

Dont forget to remove the values in HashMaps after a Player disconnects from the server to avoid memory-leak.